DB Error: unknown database when creating a CiviMail mailing
I updated from CiviCRM v5.70.2 to v5.73 (running Drupal 10.2.6, PHP 8.1 and MySQL 8).  During general upgrade testing, we run into an error with creating a test mailing in CiviMail.  This issue affects both Mosaico and Traditional mailings.  We get the following database error displayed:

I could find nothing in any of the usual logs (Drupal, CiviCRM, MySQL or Apache) and eventually took a look at the console:
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"error_code":-1,"sql":"ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT civi_0","debug_info":"ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT civi_0 [nativecode=1305 ** SAVEPOINT civi_0 does not exist]","entity":"Attachment","action":"get","is_error":1,"error_message":"DB Error: unknown error","debug_information":"ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT civi_0"}

and
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"error_code":0,"entity":"Mailing","action":"create","is_error":1,"error_message":"Mailing has not been saved, Content maybe out of date, please refresh the page and try again"}

The issue seems to be to do with the temporary saving of the mailing. We see a brief 'saving' message in the top right hand corner and then the DB Error: Unknown database box appears. Any changes to the mailing that elicit a background save seems to cause this error.
I had no idea what issue I was dealing with here - this seems to be to do with an Ajax request and Angular...

After a week of no luck, I was just about to ask this question, when I got a tip on the Town Square CiviCRM Matter Most forum (thank you @seamuslee)
The entire problem was to do with Composer patches.  I did some more searching and found the answer here:
CiviMail "DB error": suspected core bug relating to attachment replace api
@Samuele.Masetto's answer of applying patches with the following line:
composer config extra.enable-patching true

A number of patches were added and the problem has gone away.  I hope this helps others as the issue seems to be intermittent.
